# Django Swagger example code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

i am documenting api usin django swagger 0.3.5 and i am seeing that in examples there is a space for Example Value,
  try :
[here](http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus)

how can i create the same in my swagger view?

Answer (score 0):

Chris, your question is not very clear, can you elaborate more?
If you are asking if it is possible to specify a property in a swagger object that has a space in it. For exemple in the yml file definition, then you simply have to escape the space..

ex:

```
PROPERTY WITH SPACE:
  type: string
```

should be written as:

```
PROPERTY\ WITH\ SPACE:
  type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the answer mentioned below for explanation on how to modify your swagger API and on how to add and modify parameter properties.Using the Core API will allow you to customize your swagger documentation for your app. Hope it helps

[Find the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461561/6816939)