# Django Rest Swagger APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I made an API and want to make swagger doc. I don't develop any Serializes for that.

> Views.py

```
class DeliveryView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (XMLRenderer,)

    def get_campaign_vast(self, request, *args):
        return response

    def get(self, request):
        return self.get_campaign_vast(request, data)

    def post(self, request):
        """ 
        This text is the description for this API
        ---
        param1 -- A first parameter
        param2 -- A second parameter
        """
        data = request.data
        return self.get_campaign_vast(request, data)
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Add Delivery')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',schema_view),
    url(r'^', include('deliverymanagment.urls')),
]
```

I want to get all the parameters in Swagger which i am not getting.

[i am not able to get parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa6xN.png)

i am using:

> django-rest-swagger==2.1.1
>
> djangorestframework==3.5.3

Comment: So you use yaml docs, this feature is no more supported in the django-swagger. I have the same problem, could you ping me if you find the solution?

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov kindly go through the answer and ask if that still does not answer your queries

Comment: @RagulParani Really I can't test it because I already switched to the native Docs of the DRF

Answer (score 15):

Consider using the `GenericAPIView` instead as this will generate the documentation. It is a bit of a hack using this when the endpoint does not relate to a model, but it does work.

As an example, the following code will create an endpoint that only accepts post requests and is documented within swagger using the seralizer.

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

class SomeThing(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid() is False:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        res = do_magic(**serializer.data)
        return Response(res)
```

Comment: Classes inheriting from GenericAPIView should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method. So I had to add `def get_queryset(self): pass`

Comment: I have a class inherited from UpdateAPIView. And an update method in it. If I call the endpoint through postman it works fine. But the endpoint is not registered in swagger. Why?
Although another class inherited from ModelViewSet is documented in swagger

Answer (score 8):

The `get_swagger_view()` method does not give you the control to add parameters and descriptions to the urls in your app

The solution for this is to use **explicit schema definition**. You can create a Document which is a representation of the Core API schema container. Go through the following link. Read the Core API section

[Core API schema generator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#schemagenerator)

This will require you to create a schema for the urls and the parameters that are used in your Application.

Create a file for swagger

> swagger.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import renderer_classes, api_view
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer
import coreapi
from rest_framework import response
# noinspection PyArgumentList
@api_view()
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    print("---inside schema view-----")
    # noinspection PyArgumentList
    schema = coreapi.Document(
    title='Your Title',
    url='Your host url',
    content={
        'search': coreapi.Link(
            url='/search/',
            action='get',
            fields=[
                coreapi.Field(
                    name='from',
                    required=True,
                    location='query',
                    description='City name or airport code.'
                ),
                coreapi.Field(
                    name='to',
                    required=True,
                    location='query',
                    description='City name or airport code.'
                ),
                coreapi.Field(
                    name='date',
                    required=True,
                    location='query',
                    description='Flight date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.'
                )
            ],
            description='Return flight availability and prices.'
        )
    }
)
    # schema = generator.get_schema(request)
    return response.Response(schema)
```

For explanation on `coreapi.Document`, `coreapi.Field`, `coreapi.Link` kindly refer to the above mentioned link.

Create the url for the swagger docs:

> urls.py

```
url('^docs', swagger.schema_view)
```