# how to deal with python decorators in a class hierarchy?

Tags: python, django, oop, decorator, python-decorators

I'm developing a Django project using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I also have used [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for documentation purposes.

Long story short: I'm using class-based views and I have some APIs which are so similar and I decided to make a super-class and implement common parts of the APIs in it! For being more clear:

```
class MySuperApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [<some permission classes>]

    def uncommon(self):
        pass  # to be override in subclasses

    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=request_body, responses=api_responses)
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some common stuff here
        self.uncommon()
        # do some other common stuff here
```

And I just override `uncommon` method in child-classes:

```
class SomeCustomApi(MySuperApiView):
    def uncommon(self):
        # do specific things here
```

It works fine but I have a little problem: Every Api have its own `api_responses` which is initialized in the `swagger_auto_schema` decorator in super-class! And it's not possible to change it!

What do you recommend for such a situation? I really want to do OOP and observe DRY principle.

Comment: It looks like `api_responses` is being passed as an argument to `swagger_auto_schema`.  Where is that value defined?  How will it be different between the subclasses?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  It's a `dict` and it have to be different for every Api. I declared them outside of views and the `api_responses` which you can see is `None` and it's been declared outside of view. However it can be inside if it can help. I tried to declare it inside and change its value in child-classes but it doesn't work (cause it shouldn't)

Comment: @HamidrezaAhmadi I think your question might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311888/django-rest-swagger-apiview
They use django-rest-swagger which is now depreciated, but it may help in the reflexion.

Have you tried specifiyng the HTTP method?
`@swagger_auto_schema(method='GET', responses={200: UserSerializer(many=True)})`

Comment: @ThisIsMyName No! It's totally irrelevant. I do know how to deal with swagger and the framework which I'm using. The main question is in the title. I'm looking for best practice of dealing with decorators in OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the best way to do such a thing in Django! (So yes, I don't know how to deal with such a problem in other frameworks or languages!)
I moved `swagger_auto_schema` decorator to child-class using a class decorator named [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). So first of all I had to import this method:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
```

And then I changed super-class and child-class like this:

```py
class MySuperApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [<some permission classes>]

    def uncommon(self):
        pass  # to be override in subclasses

    # <I removed decorator from here!>
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some common stuff here
        self.uncommon()
        # do some other common stuff here
```

```py
api_responses =  # responses which belong to "SomeCustomApi"

@method_decorator(name='post',
                  decorator=swagger_auto_schema(request_body=request_body,
                                                responses=api_responses))
class SomeCustomApi(MySuperApiView):
    def uncommon(self):
        # do specific things here
```

It works totaly fine :) however I prefer a solution in which I don't have to repeat the decorator and instead, just initialize the `responses` parameter. If you face such a problem in other languages and you have the answer for another language, please post your answer.